# How to get up time for the terminal

Tags: scripts

How to get the uptime from. The terminal. And in a bash file but only the uptime no other infomAtion

I would like it to be on one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in a terminal just run the following command.

```
uptime
```

This will display your current uptime plus a little ekstra information.

Mine says.

```
08:44:21 up 1:05, 2 users, load average: 0,00, 0,01, 0,05
```

So my uptime is 1 hour and 5 minutes. In a bash script to only get the uptime I'd use

```
uptime | awk '{print $3}'
```

This will show only the 3rd section of the uptime command.

Comment: Be careful what the third section is. Since I have an uptime of '3 days, 1:41', I get just the number 3.

Comment: Ah okay. Thought it was in the same column for displaying that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo $SECONDS` , gives you the uptime of a terminal in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the top command to know the uptime.

> top

In the top of the terminal, you can view the uptime status.

Comment: While this is true, it is a continuously ongoing command, so it's would not fit well with a bash script.

Comment: @DanJohansen `top` has a batch mode, which I'd say is meant for scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the up time using different methods:

- using `w` command

  ```
  $ w

  11:12:21 up 22:08,  3 users,  load average: 0.28, 0.32, 0.40
  ```

  If you just want the time nothing else:

  ```
  $ w | grep up | awk '{print $3}'

  22:08,
  ```
- using `uptime` as described in other answer
- using `top` as described in other answer
- using `utmp`, you can see since when you are on:

  ```
  $ last utmp

  wtmp begins Mon Jun  1 08:29:04 2015
  ```

utmp maintains a full accounting of the current status of the system, system boot time (used by uptime), recording user logins at which terminals, logouts, system events.

Comment: what is exactly `utmp`? Just curious because it shows me June 11th, it's like my computer hasn't been turned off since then?

Comment: Check the definition in the answer

Comment: Indeed you use utmp in your answer :) `last ` command read from `utmp` `wtmp` and `btmp`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/uptime | awk '{print $1}'
```

will give you the uptime expressed in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you when your system has booted and print uptime in brackets also:

```
last -x | grep boot | head -n 1
```